# How to use mallet for topic modelling API

Tags: java, mallet

Is there anyone here have successfully using mallet API for topic modelling. i'm find it difficult to understand, even until know i don't know ho to import my txt as the data. do you guys know any good source to learn about the code? i don't find the mallet.cs.umass.edu is helpfull.

PS: I'm not talking about the command line guide, so please don't give me that kind of answers.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've seen the tutorial slides? http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/mallet-tutorial.pdf These are the best resource for understanding data importing.

The example code may be the most useful otherwise. Here's an example of the topic model API that includes data import, topic training, and some code to extract topic-word distributions: https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/blob/master/src/cc/mallet/examples/TopicModel.java